# Is there a way to change the width of the <code> HTML tag?

Tags: html, css, tags, width

I've noticed that any modification of the `<code>`'s style with respect to its width doesn't have any effect. It's seems to always be set to "auto".

I'm just trying to have some code written inside a `<code>` tag (this tag is mandatory due to some known iBooks bugs) that has 100% width. One workaround is to put the `<code>` inside a `<div>` which has a 100% background style. This works OK but I'll have to deal with a couple of hundred `<code>` tags... This is the reason I would prefer just to be able to modify the `<code>`'s width.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1 Notice, CODE is considered and "inline" element, which width/height does not affect as it's width is determined by the content.  Per Rob W below, you have to convert it to render as a block, which inline-block can work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<code>` elements are inline elements. Setting a height or width on these do not have any effect on their size.

Use `display:inline-block`::

```
code {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100px; /* Whatever. The <code>'s width will change */
}
```

Comment: @Starx Thanks for the reply. Worked out great :).

Answer (score 5):

Add a `display: block` or `inline-block` as per your requirement to the `code` element. Rest should work as planned

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/YnQ5m/)

Comment: This method does not allow other content at the same line: http://jsfiddle.net/YnQ5m/1/

Comment: @RobW, Generally when you displaying codes, its not necessary to show them in a straight line. That's hardly the case for me.

Comment: The question, and your answer is full of `<code>` examples. Markdown turns backticks into `<code>` environments.

Comment: @RobW, That is not the point. And either way, I have also written in my answer to include `inline-block` to but `as per the requirement`

Comment: If the intent is to make the element 100% wide, as the question suggests, then `display: block` is preferable: better browser support (and more logical—if it’s 100% wide, it isn’t really inline).

Answer (score 2):

I think great way to solve this problem is by using **CSS Layout - Overflow** Here i have used Tailwind CSS. you can use raw CSS to do this task.

```
     <pre className="overflow-auto bg-gray-900 text-white p-5">
        <code className="text-base font-light ">{yourCode}</code>
      </pre>
```