# Can not get horizontal scroll bar on <code>

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, prismjs

No matter what I do, I can NOT get the `code` block to create its own scroll bar on smaller breakpoints. It continuosly creates a full page scroll bar.

[here is the live preview](https://portfolio-git-blog-post-jpwallace22.vercel.app/blog/test) with the error.

I tried every form of `overflow` property. I tried wrapping it in a another `div` with `overflow: scroll;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code` elements are inline so width/height doesn't work as expected exactly unless you make it a block/inline-block.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9670566/1265817

Another approach would be to set the `pre` wrapper to a set `max-width` of the screen width.

```
pre {
   max-width: 95vw;
}
```